# Creating custom processing tool (sibling of Batch Nominatim geocoder) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, algorithm

I want to create a custom processing tool for geocoding in QGIS.

It will reproduce the ["Batch Nominatim geocoder"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#batch-nominatim-geocoder) geoalgorithm, besides several things:

- another URL of a geocoder will be used instead of the [the Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Search/)
- there will be no limitations in requests

From the "Batch Nominatim geocoder" I would like to inherit: GUI, functionality and logic.

I tried to create a model in the Graphical Modeler and export it as a Python Processing Script, however it does not look like what I need.

```py
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : geocoding
Group : STMA
With QGIS : 32205
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class Geocoding(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('Adressen', 'adressen', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVector], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Geocodiert', 'geocodiert', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Batch Nominatim geocoder
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'Anschrift',
            'INPUT': parameters['Adressen'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Geocodiert']
        }
        outputs['BatchNominatimGeocoder'] = processing.run('native:batchnominatimgeocoder', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Geocodiert'] = outputs['BatchNominatimGeocoder']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'geocoding'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'geocoding'

    def group(self):
        return 'STMA'

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Geocoding()
```

I could find this geoalgorithm in [QGIS/src/core/geocoding/qgsnominatimgeocoder.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/e6b39077a232e034ab1e57937c9eaf79538650c2/src/core/geocoding/qgsnominatimgeocoder.cpp) on the GitHub. This is the part with an URL:

```cpp
QgsNominatimGeocoder::QgsNominatimGeocoder( const QString &countryCodes, const QString &endpoint )
  : QgsGeocoderInterface()
  , mCountryCodes( countryCodes )
  , mEndpoint( QStringLiteral( "https://nominatim.qgis.org/search" ) )
```

But C++ is simply beyond my programming skills.

Another (maybe a feasible) solution is to reproduce the ["Google Maps Geocoder"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/google_maps_geocoder/) plugin developed by @ndawson. It is basically a processing tool, similar to "Batch Nominatim geocoder" but implemented for Google Maps. This plugin is available on the GitHub: https://github.com/north-road/qgis-google-maps-geocoder. Unfortunately the geocoding in this plugin is dependent on the [`QgsGoogleMapsGeocoder`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGoogleMapsGeocoder.html) class, not [a simple request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) to Google Maps API.

What are my available approaches?

Perhaps it is in general impossible because I simply collide with copyrights of the core developer (Mathieu Pellerin @nirvn).

Comment: No colliding since QGIS project is in GPL2 : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/COPYING

Comment: Ref.: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html

Comment: Note that 90% of what these implementations do is stitching together core library classes to create request objects that conform with the respective API, sending and receiving *http(s)* requests, and parsing the respective API responses - some sanity checks aside. What this means for you is that you will either have to rewrite these 90% in *C++* to suit your own API - or simply write an own, independent Python plugin to begin with.

Comment: I would just rewrite the script of batchnominatim from scratch in Python, thats probably the most straight forward option. Even if you don't know c++, you can still get the logic of the code. About license I dont see an issue. Even if you use parts of others code, most of them allow usage by naming the authors or under the same terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good point to start is this tutorial: [Building a Processing Plugin (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_plugin.html#building-a-processing-plugin-qgis3) by @spatialthoughts.

This reference shows how to develop a custom processing plugin using the ["Plugin Builder"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/) plugin for creating a plugin template which at the beginning can imitate the desired GUI of the "Batch Nominatim geocoder" geoalgorithm, see image below.

[image: input]

After one shall try to modify the *.ui* file of this processing plugin and embed the parameter of the 'Address field' using the [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools), as also demonstrated in this tutorial [Building a Python Plugin (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html#building-a-python-plugin-qgis3) by @spatialthoughts.

Last but not least adjust plugin functionality and logic correspondingly.

---

**References:**

- [Qt Designer vs Qt Quick Designer vs Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559332/qt-designer-vs-qt-quick-designer-vs-qt-creator)