# Reuse Extent menu from processing tools

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, extents, pyqt5

Actually I'm using [QgsExtentGroupBox](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsExtentGroupBox.html) in my plugin and it works fine.

Now I want to make the GUI more compact and therefor I want to implement the extent menu a lot of processing tools are using:

[image]

I really would like to have a look at the source code of these implementations, but can't figure out how [Processing Code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing) is organized. For example, where is the implementation of the "Write Vector Tiles" GUI to have a look how the coded the dropdown menu to select the extents?

Comment: Please see one of my previous threads: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/434233/99589